# Issue with authorization in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am learning CakePhp, following the book provided in their website, I created users who can add posts in a blog tutorial, but in authorization there is a function to determine the owner of the post, which is not working, 
this is the authorization part where the function is called:

```
    if (in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete'))) {
        $postId = (int) $this->request->params['pass'][0];
        if ($this->Post->isOwnedBy($postId, $user['id'])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

There is the function,

```
    public function isOwnedBy($post, $user) {
         return $this->field('id', array('id' => $post, 'user_id' => $user)) === $post;
    }
```

What is wrong with this, please suggest.

Comment: What exactly is not working? You can't add posts, edit them, what?

Comment: I can not edit or delete a post but can post a new one.